# Nginx wants to execute a file when .php in url

Tags: nginx, php

I recently moved from apache to a nginx webserver.

I want the following to happen:

If the file exists return the content
Except when its a php file then pass to php
when 404 call index.php with the $query_string

**So for example:**

example.com/jfkldsajlkfdsa => return content index.php rendered by php

example.com/image.jpg => return the contents

example.com/aphpfilethatexists.php => return content aphpfilethatexists.php rendered by php

example.com/aphpfilethatdoesntexists.php => return content index.php rendered by php

**Now is the situation:**

example.com/jfkldsajlkfdsa => return content index.php rendered by php

example.com/image.jpg => return the contents

example.com/aphpfilethatexists.php => return content aphpfilethatexists.php rendered by php

example.com/aphpfilethatdoesntexists.php => returns php error that the file doens't exist `File not found.`

**I use the following configuration:**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/269;
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass phpserver;
}

location ~ /.svn/ {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to remember that this isn't evaluated in document order. Regular expression locations are done first. So your try_files doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for no files/directories/symlinks existence using [`!-e`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) operator inside the location block (which serves `.php`)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?$query_string break;
    }
    ....
```